# TimeSpan Issue in EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, timespan

I have a problem querying PostgreSQL database using EF Core 3.1.

The query is very simple

```
var gamesQuery = this.dbContext.Games.Where(game => game.StartTime > DateTime.Now).AsQueryable();

// 'request.TimeFrom' is of type System.TimeSpan and the value is populated
gamesQuery = gamesQuery.Where(game => game.StartTime.TimeOfDay >= request.TimeFrom);

// .ToList()-int here causes the exception.
var games = gamesQuery.ToList();
```

The exception message clearly states that the query can not be translated:

*"The LINQ expression 'DbSet\r\n    .Where(g => g.StartTime > DateTime.Now)\r\n    .Where(g => g.StartTime.TimeOfDay >= __request_TimeFrom_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."*

The problem is that the same query works fine in .NET Core 2.2.
I haven't found anything about the problem yet.

Someone know what is the reason about this one or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried iterating line by line to find the individual entry that is causing the problem?

Comment: The problem is in `game => game.StartTime.TimeOfDay`. You should use DbFunctions class to extract parts of datetime. Or check against Datetime variable (just set the same dates).

Comment: @Alex the problem is not in the data itself. It doesn't matter if there is data in the table or not. Most likely translating the IQueryable object to SQL brakes the things.

Comment: @balbelias as I see in .NET Core the [DbFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-3.1#extension-methods) class is accessible through [SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions?view=efcore-3.1) class which is provided only in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll, so it is irrelevant considering I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently PostgreSQL EF Core 3.x query provider does not support translation of `DateTime.TimeOfDay` - see the `TODO` comment in the [source code](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/blob/dev/src/EFCore.PG/Query/ExpressionTranslators/Internal/NpgsqlDateTimeMemberTranslator.cs#L69).

Most likely it "worked" in 2.x by silently using client evaluation. But implicit client evaluation [has been removed in 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client) and there is no way to turn it back on.

You can try the following equivalent construct:

```
.Where(game => (game.StartTime - game.StartTime.Date) >= request.TimeFrom)
```

At least it doesn't produce the aforementioned exception.

If it doesn't work, take their advice and switch explicitly to client evaluation by inserting `AsEnumerable()` in the appropriate place before the non translatable expression.

Comment: Very good point, but I think the problem could be somewhere else. 
Exactly same line of code works perfectly fine with Npgsql 2.2.4 and I'm not seeing any changes of the handling of DateTime.TimeOfDay in the file you have provided since [version 2.2.4](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/blob/v2.2.4/src/EFCore.PG/Query/ExpressionTranslators/Internal/NpgsqlDateTimeMemberTranslator.cs)

The workaround wont work in my case, cause 2020-01-20 T15:00 >= 2019-12-29 T16:00 should return false, but It will return true in your example.

Comment: Are we sure it really worked in 2.x? I mean, not silently switching to client evaluation? And since 3.x removed client eval…. But you are right that the suggested workaround is not equivalent.

Comment: I have just tested my 2.2.4 solution and it worked just fine.There are no changes in this particular lines of code.
I'm comparing both solutions and trying to figure out the differences (there are some architectural modification since migration to 3.1).

Comment: You seem to be missing the **client evaluation** concept which probably makes your 2.x solution "working". Add `optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));` to your 2.2.4 solution and check again - I doubt it would work if the Npgsql provider code is the same.

Comment: See, down side or not, in 3.x it's gone. They don't do that for you anymore. As the error message indicates, you are supposed to find/choose the solution.

Comment: You are right. I have just checked debug log of 2.x solution and there is this line: _Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'where ([game].Time.TimeOfDay >= __request_TimeFrom_0)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally_

Comment: This is exactly the answer. Also the example works as expected. Thanks, you are great!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet but one solution could be to save TimeOfDay into database beside of DateTime property. Then you just compare it with your TimeSpan variable.